# Convert binary data to HEX in Google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-api

I have a Google sheet document with a column containing binary data. The binary data is 4 32-bit numbers. This is an example ASCII hex representation of that binary data from one cell: `c0a80123000006150000000180004203`.

Is there a way in Google sheets to convert this binary number to hex string. I'm looking for something like: `BIN2HEX(data[0]) = "0xc0"`. Regular `BIN2HEX` doesn't work because the data is larger than it can handle.

[Raw text sample file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1kwBseNotyHPI7_gfOXDaKtAV8F1Wl4SK). [Converted google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ul62eCZmuuk3vhLFXQu133GpchWlleZnn5-emYmYsE0/edit?usp=sharing).

---

Update:

Based on one suggestion I've created a Google API script to process the binary data. However, the results come strange to say the least.

```js
function extractip(binary_data) {
  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(binary_data);
  var ip1 = blob.getBytes()[0];
  var ip2 = blob.getBytes()[1];
  var ip3 = blob.getBytes()[2];
  var ip4 = blob.getBytes()[3];
  
  return Utilities.formatString("%u.%u.%u.%u", ip1, ip2, ip3, ip4);
}
```

The first 4 bytes in the binary blob represent an IP address, in the form of 192.168.0.X in the attached example. However, the output comes back something like `-17.-65.-67.-17`.

Comment: can this page of Google Sheets Docs Editor Help page mentioning BIN2HEX
The BIN2HEX function converts a signed binary number to signed hexadecimal format.be useful to you <<https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093133?hl=en#>>

Comment: I've tried the `BIN2HEX`. However, the original number is essentially 128 bit, which `BIN2HEX` can't handle

Comment: In order to correctly understanding your situation, can you provide a sample spreadsheet? Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: @Tanaike - example added.

Comment: @ilya1725 Thank you for replying. I saw it. But I couldn't understand about it. And also I cannot understand about the relation with ``c0a80123000006150000000180004203``. Can you explain about each values? If you can do, please update your question. I think that such information will help users think of about your issue.

Comment: @Tanaike so the blobs in the last column are 128-bit binary numbers. `c0a80123000006150000000180004203` listed in the question is an ASCII representation of that binary data; just one example for one cell. It is what get if you run a `hexdump` on a binary file.

Comment: @ilya1725 You want to convert the binary data to hex data at the column "G". If my understanding is correct, as a sample, when the value of "G2" is converted, can you provide the value you want? By this, we can compare with the result of several methods we think.

Comment: @Tanaike Sorry for confusion. I would like to manipulate some segments of the binary blob. In order to do that I either need to be able to access the data as an array of binaries, then `BIN2HEX` would work, or convert the whole thing into a string representing hex values.

Comment: @ilya1725 For example, how about using Google Apps Script? In Google Apps Script, there is a method of [``Utilities.newBlob()``](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#newblobdata_6) for converting the binary data to a blob. By this, you can convert it to byte array and hex data. But I'm not sure about the input and output you want. So I had asked about it. I apologize for my poor English skill.

Comment: @Tanaike `Utilities.newBlob()` will work, since there is nothing simpler. I've tried it and for some reason the data comes back weird. It looks like the way the binary data is transferred to the function is in the wrong format.

Comment: @ilya1725 Thank you for replying. In order to confirm your situation, can you provide the current script and/or a shared spreadsheet? And your shared file is a text file. Is this the same situation with you?

Comment: @Tanaike I've added the examples. One raw text file, the other is converted Google sheet.

Comment: @ilya1725 Thank you for replying and sharing the samples. I proposed a modified script. Could you please confirm it? If this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you @Tanaike. It does work correctly on the data in the worksheet.

Comment: @ilya1725 I'm glad your issue was resolved. Although I'm not sure whether this is useful for your situation, I added a sample modification. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: @Tanaikeyes, it works. Thank you for your help. Your code is much fancier than I would use, but I'm just new to the Google Apps script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this modification?

At Google Apps Script, the data which was converted by `Utilities.newBlob(data).getBytes()` is the bytes array of the signed hexadecimal. It is required to convert the bytes array to the unsigned hexadecimal.

#### Modified script:

```
function extractip(binary_data) {
  var byteAr = Utilities.newBlob(binary_data).getBytes();
  return byteAr.map(function(e) {return ("0" + (e < 0 ? e + 256 : e).toString(16)).slice(-2)}).join("");
}
```

#### Note:

- When you use this, for example, please put `=extractip(G2)` to "H2" like your shared spreadsheet.

### Edit:

If you want to directly retrieve the decimal number like `192.168.0.X`, please modify like below. This is a sample modification. So please modify it to your situation.

#### From:

```
return byteAr.map(function(e) {return ("0" + (e < 0 ? e + 256 : e).toString(16)).slice(-2)}).join("");
```

#### To:

```
return byteAr.map(function(e) {return e < 0 ? e + 256 : e}).join(",");
```